# Swear filter case sensitive

Tags: php, filter, case-sensitive

I have a little problem with my function:

```
function swear_filter($string){
    $search = array(
        'bad-word',
    );
    $replace = array(
        '****',
    );
    return preg_replace($search , $replace, $string);
}
```

It should transform "bad-word" to "****" but the problem is the case sensivity

eg. if the user type "baD-word" it doesn't work.

Comment: [clbuttic.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in your `$search` array are *not* regular expressions.

First, fix that:

```
$search = array(
    '/bad-word/',
);
```

Then, you can apply the `i` flag for case-insensitivity:

```
$search = array(
    '/bad-word/i',
);
```

You don't need the `g` flag to match *globally* (i.e. more than once each) because `preg_replace` will handle that for you.

However, you could probably do with using [the word boundary metacharacter `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid matching your "bad-word" string *inside another word*. This may have consequences on how you form your list of "bad words".

```
$search = array(
    '/\bbad-word\b/i',
);
```

### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/vkURkJE6)

---

If you don't want to pollute `$search` with these implementation details, then you can do the same thing a bit more programmatically:

```
$search = array_map(
   create_function('$str', 'return "/\b" . preg_quote($str, "/") . "\b/i";'),
   $search
);
```

<sup>(I've not used the recent PHP lambda syntax because codepad doesn't support it; look it up if you are interested!)</sup>

### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/B4mp7eaz)

---

**Update** Full code:

```
function swear_filter($string){
    $search = array(
        'bad-word',
    );

    $replace = array(
        '****',
    );

    // regex-ise input
    $search = array_map(
       create_function('$str', 'return "/\b" . preg_quote($str, "/") . "\b/i";'),
       $search
    );

    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to match on word boundaries too, all you'll get "classic" replaced with "cl****ic"?

Comment: @chibacity: Yes, probably. :)

Comment: There are a surprising number of these cases if you go for straight string replacement...

Comment: @chibacity: Good thing I fixed the post, then!

Comment: Ah yes I see, +1 from me then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
'/bad-word/i',
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you even need to use regex?

```
function swear_filter($string){
    $search = array(
        'bad-word',
    );
    if (in_array(strtolower($string), $search){
        return '****';
    }
    return $search
}
```

makes the following assumptions.

1) $string contains characters acceptable in the current local

2) all contents of the $search array are lowercase

edit: 3) Entire string consists of bad word

I suppose this would only work if the string was split and evaluated on a per word basis.

Comment: It also assumes that the entire input consists of the bad word.